# Isolate scope doesn't work the way I think it should

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have a fundamental misconception about isolate scopes and I can't figure out what it is.

I have a controller and directive:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.zed = "ZZZZZ";
        $scope.zz = function() {
            return "yep";
        };
    }])
.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        controller: "MyCtrl",
        templateUrl: 'a/path/to/my_template.html',
        scope: {
            z: '@'
        }
    };
```

and the template:

```
<div>***{{z}} {{zz()}} ^^^ {{zed}} </div>
```

and the use of the directive:

```
<div my-directive z="yabba"/>
```

When I run this app, the value of 'yabba' is displayed for `z`. I'm good with that.  The isolate scope makes this possible.  However, the template reaches right into the `$scope` and is able to run a function and grab a scalar (`zed` and `zz`).  I don't want that.  The controller needs access to `$scope` since the model upon which I'll eventually operate has to be assembled from $scope data.

My desire is to limit the directive to as little information as possible.

I would like the `$scope` to be available to the controller but not the directive. I want the directive to have to gets its data from the controller exclusively. I tried to add `z` and `zed` to the isolate scope but this did nothing helpful.

How can I do this? Or, is my approach simply foreign to Angular and bad?  If so, that's cool, please explain to me the better approach. And, please, use small words.

Answer (score 0):

You are stepping on your toes by including your controller in the directive. Just delete this line from your directive and it will behave as you guessed: controller: "MyCtrl",

Here is a plunker to mess around with. You can see that your isolated scope is working as it should with the line commented out. Just un-comment that line again and see how you now have access to the controller scope.

```
.directive("myDirective", function() {
return {
    restrict: "AE",
    // controller: "MyCtrl", REMOVE THIS LINE!!!
    templateUrl: 'a/path/to/my_template.html',
    scope: {
        z: '@'
    }
};
```

[Plunker playground with your code](http://plnkr.co/edit/RbAevZhHDdoYK69AEkxI?p=preview)

By the way, there is nothing foreign in your code. Isolated scope is a great feature to use with custom directives. There are many ways to work with Angularjs 1.+.  This may not be the case when Angularjs 2.0 is released. In your example, the controller is not needed within the directive. I rarely include controllers, and I most always isolate scope. Good luck! Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I will eventually have some meat in the controller - a model being watched, that will be the data source for the directive. Surely some status flags and functions, too.  How will the directive find these things?